# Issues Reading txt files

Tags: r

I want to text a .txt file in R but I keep getting an embedded null error.

I have tried this code:

`text_df = read.delim2(testfile, header = TRUE, sep = ',')`

The original file ("testfile") looks like this:

```
UPC,HSY Item Description,Hsy Seasonal Segmentation,Store Nbr,Store Name,Building City,Building State/Prov,Building Postal Code,Store Type,WM Date,SeasonAndYear,OH_Qty,POS_Qty,POS_Sales
"0001070006638","Whprs Rbn Egg 13.75OZ","EAS $2.98 Candy Dish",1,"ROGERS, AR","ROGERS","AR","72756","Supercenter",1/27/2018 12:00:00 AM,"EAS2018",0,0,0.0000
"0001070006638","Whprs Rbn Egg 13.75OZ","EAS $2.98 Candy Dish",1,"ROGERS, AR","ROGERS","AR","72756","Supercenter",1/30/2018 12:00:00 AM,"EAS2018",0,0,0.0000
"0001070006638","Whprs Rbn Egg 13.75OZ","EAS $2.98 Candy Dish",1,"ROGERS, AR","ROGERS","AR","72756","Supercenter",2/2/2018 12:00:00 AM,"EAS2018",0,0,0.0000
```

I keep getting this error:

> Warning messages: 1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep =
>   sep, quote = quote,  :   line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls 2:
>   In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, 
>   :   line 2 appears to contain embedded nulls 3: In read.table(file =
>   file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :   line 3 appears
>   to contain embedded nulls 4: In read.table(file = file, header =
>   header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :   line 4 appears to contain
>   embedded nulls 5: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep =
>   sep, quote = quote,  :   line 5 appears to contain embedded nulls 6:
>   In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,
>   :   embedded nul(s) found in input

Comment: you are in windows?

Comment: Your have a problem with Store Name: `"ROGERS, AR"` has a comma in a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = read.table(yourFile, quote = '"', sep = ",", header = T)
```

This should treat the comma inside "ROGERS, AR" as part of the string and not as a separator.

Comment: It does not work. I have the same error. Any other ideas? Thanks!